# Latest update to Android SDK has made my x86 AVD unusably slow to load .apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, haxm

For the last few months I've had a nice set up with AVD and HAXM (v4). Now I've moved up a couple of versions and recreated my x86 virtual machines (because I only had the Google API x86 machine before). Whereas before it would take max 10 seconds to push my game over from Eclipse (not an Android Studio user yet for legacy reasons) now it is taking 2 minutes or more if my game ever gets there at all.

Anyone else having this problem and could help me trace the update more precisely since I updated all my tools/platforms/builders etc etc at the same time?

I could almost go back to using ARM emulator the x86 version is so bad now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried genymotion.

https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Free for non-commercial use.

The devices you start run on virtual box and show up like real usb devices. They are a little slow to start ( better than stock ), but they update really fast when you push to them.